# Adding class to <div> tag causes delay in font rendering (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 bootstrap 4 picture cards, in a deck. They flip when clicked to reveal information on the back of them. Some of that information is wrapped in a div which I wanted to be at the bottom of the card, to do this I added the class `align-self-end` as well as some css for that class. This worked just fine. However, just adding this class causes a ~500ms delay in the information appearing on the back of the card when clicked. I am clueless as to what is causing this.

**Here is my html for the card:**

```
    <div class="card mb-4 mt-4" style="max-width: 300px; min-width: 300px display: block;" data-clickable="true">
    <div class="card-inner">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1420x1933" class="card-img" alt="...">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <div class="cardContent">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card Title</h5>
                <p class="card-text info">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="alignToEnd">
                <p class="smallinfo"><b>1: </b>John</p>
                <p class="smallinfo"><b>2: </b>Smith</p>
                <p class="smallinfo"><b>3: </b>2008</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And here is the css for align-self-end:**

```
    .alignToEnd {
    -ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex-end;
    -webkit-box-align:left;
    -ms-flex-align:left;
    align-items:left;
    -webkit-box-pack:left;
    -ms-flex-pack:left;
    justify-content:left;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

I have tried this with a simplified class which achieves a similar result, `align-self-end` with the following css:

```
.align-self-end {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:2rem;
}
```

Here is my codepen. The card on the left has no class, the card on the right has the class to move the info to the end and when clicked the information on the back takes longer to appear. You will need to refresh the page after the first click to refresh the cache and repeat the effect.

https://codepen.io/Darlton29/pen/bGVojWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a rendering bug in Chrome (Firefox doesn't have the problem). The combination of this transition and the absolute positioning of the `alignToEnd`-div makes this happen in Chrome.

A solution would be to work with flex like this:

```
   <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="cardContent flex-grow-1">
         <h5 class="card-title">Card Title</h5>
         <p class="card-text info">This card has align-self-end class on the bottom div and loads much slower. </p>
      </div>
      <div>
         <p class="smallinfo"><b>1: </b>John</p>
         <p class="smallinfo"><b>2: </b>Smith</p>
         <p class="smallinfo"><b>3: </b>2008</p>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I used Bootstrap utilities for convenience.

Comment: Thank you- this works. I am curious- how is that code making the items John Smith 2008 aligned to the bottom?

Comment: I used the `flex-column` to make all direct children of that div stacking up vertically (default flex direction is horizontal), and then I used the `flex-grow-1` class (same as `flex-grow: 1;` in CSS) to make the first div take as much space of it's parent as possible, pushing the other div down.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. I think I understand- I'll try comment it. How would I then adjust the margin between the three above mentioned items and the bottom of the card?

Comment: You can add a margin on the div that wraps the 3 items if you want.